# geom_vline not showing up

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am doing a scatterplot with a vertical line as intercept over a x-axis date variable, and the vertical line doesn't show up.

I have tried with and without converting the intercept to number.

```
dis <- read.csv("dis.csv")

selection.districts <- dis[which(dis$district=="Kien Svay"),]

ggplot(selection.districts, aes(x=date, y=radiance)) + 
geom_point() +
geom_vline(aes(xintercept=as.numeric(intercept))) +
geom_smooth(method="auto") +
labs(x="Date", y = "Radiance")
```

I expect to see a vertical line based on the value of the intercept variable of the dataset. You can find a data sample to reproduce it here:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nreguera/NightLights/master/dis.csv

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need the `aes` call in the `geom_vline` entry. Just set `xintercept` to whatever value you want.

Comment: Looking at this more closely, are you sure you want a vertical line anyway? The date is on the x-axis.

Comment: It's not clear how 23 (the value of `intercept`) relates to a date ?

Comment: @cardinal40 I have tried wiwthout aes but it doesn´t work. It´s weird as it looks very simple thing. This is in the middle of a process so the intercept is calculated based on the district o the x-axis (a date axis).

Comment: @neilfws The number is a value calculated from the begining of a timeline, adding up the number to the start date